# Cross Validation in linear regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am trying to perform cross validation in Linear Regression, for which I am using python sklearn libraries. I have a question regarding the appropriate way of performing cross validation for a given dataset.

The two APIs that are confusing me a bit are `cross_val_score()` and any regularized cross validation algorithm, like `LassoCV()`.

As I understand, `cross_val_score` is used to get the score based on cross validation. And, it can be clubbed with `Lasso()` to achieve regularized cross validation score (Example: [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html)).

In contrast, `LassoCV()`, as [it's documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV.html) suggests, performs `Lasso`for a given range of tuning parameter (alpha or lambda).

Now, my questions are:

- Which one is a better approach (`cross_val_score` with `Lasso` or just `LassoCV`).
- What is the correct way of performing cross validation for Linear
  Regression (or other algorithms, say Logistic, NN etc.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To confuse you a bit more - consider using [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html), which will do cross validation and tune up hyperparameters.

Demo:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso, Ridge, SGDRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = \
        train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.33)

pipe = Pipeline([
    ('scale', StandardScaler()),
    ('regr', Lasso())
])

param_grid = [
    {
        'regr': [Lasso(), Ridge()],
        'regr__alpha': np.logspace(-4, 1, 6),
    },
    {
        'regr': [SGDRegressor()],
        'regr__alpha': np.logspace(-5, 0, 6),
        'regr__max_iter': [500, 1000],
    },
]

grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=param_grid, cv=3, n_jobs=-1, verbose=2)
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

predicted = grid.predict(X_test, y_test)

print('Score:\t{}'.format(grid.score(X_test, y_test)))
```

Comment: Thanks @MaxU ! I understand that instead of `cross_val_score`, we can use `GridSearchCV` with `Lasso` or `Ridge`. Then, I am curious, what are the scenarios/use cases, where `LassoCV` or `RidgeCV` can be useful?

Answer (score 0):

@PankajK,

In response to your question in the comment-

You may find Lasso regression useful when you want your model to eliminate the least important features, whereas Ridge focuses on not only fitting the data but also keeps the model weights as small as possible.

You might want to check out - 
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/hands-on-machine-learning/9781491962282/ch04.html